# Trigger Multiple Services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have two problems regarding Android Services.

First, I would like to know which is less computationally expensive? Threads or Services?

Secondly, In my main android application I have tried to trigger 2 services:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName
            .unflattenFromString("com.mrlite.service1"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    startService(intent);

    intent.setComponent(ComponentName
            .unflattenFromString("com.mrlite.service2"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    startService(intent);
```

**Service1:**

```
package com.mrlite.service1;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class Service1Activity extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        //String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("1")

        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Service 1 Started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
      super.onDestroy();
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Service 1 Destroyed");
    }
}
```

**Service 2:**

```
package com.mrlite.service2;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class Service2Activity extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        // String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("1")

        Log.e("Service 2", "Service 2 Started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service 2", "Service 2 Destroyed");
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to execute this code, only service 1 is called. Service 2 is never called.

How to trigger 2 services simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are starting your services that way? Why not do it this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service1Activity.class);
startService(intent);

intent = new Intent(this, Service2Activity.class);
startService(intent);
```

The reason it probably doesn't work the way you're doing it is because `android.intent.action.MAIN` can only be assigned to one class.

Comment: Yes, It is not possible to reside all the services within one application package. There will be a situation when one application will execute service of another application. Therefore, these services must act as separate applications.

Comment: Are there any other ways to achieve this type of behaviour? Your suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand, you can launch as many services from one application as you like.